# PlotRange is not working with MaterialShading in Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Here is a minimum example:

```
dots[x_, y_, z_] := {Green, EdgeForm[None], Sphere[{x, y, z}, 0.105], 
  Lighting -> "ThreePoint"}
With[{Aa = {0, 1, 0}, Bb = {1, 0, 0}}, 
 Graphics3D[Table[dots @@ (Aa j + Bb k), {j, 1, 20}, {k, 1, 20}], 
  Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {1.38, 6.13}, {0, 1}}]]
```

this gives the desired results as in the picture below

[image]

Now if I replace `Green` with `MaterialShading["Plastic"]` `PlotRange` is not working properly

```
dots[x_, y_, z_] := {MaterialShading["Plastic"], EdgeForm[None], 
  Sphere[{x, y, z}, 0.105], Lighting -> "ThreePoint"}
With[{Aa = {0, 1, 0}, Bb = {1, 0, 0}}, 
 Graphics3D[Table[dots @@ (Aa j + Bb k), {j, 1, 20}, {k, 1, 20}], 
  Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {1.38, 6.13}, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. However, I am not sure that `PlotRange` is specifically to blame here. In fact, the buggy behavior is actually much more obvious if you turn the Box back on (`Boxed -> True`, i.e. the default behavior): this shows that, with `MaterialShading`, items are drawn *outside* the box specified by `PlotRange`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version
(*12.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)*)
```

Try this:

```
dots[x_, y_, z_] := {{MaterialShading["Plastic"]}, EdgeForm[None], 
    Sphere[{x, y, z}, 0.105], Lighting -> "ThreePoint"}
With[{Aa = {0, 1, 0}, Bb = {1, 0, 0}}, 
  Graphics3D[Table[dots @@ (Aa j + Bb k), {j, 1, 20}, {k, 1, 20}], 
    Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {1.38, 6.13}, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image: balls]

The small change is as follows:

```
MaterialShading["Plastic"]->{MaterialShading["Plastic"]}
```

However, MaterialShading doesn't work properly with PlotRange.

Another way:

```
dots[x_, y_, z_] := Sphere[{x, y, z}, 0.105]
data = With[{Aa = {0, 1, 0}, Bb = {1, 0, 0}}, 
Table[dots @@ (Aa j + Bb k), {j, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 15}]];
Show[Map[Graphics3D[{MaterialShading["Plastic"], #}, 
Boxed -> False] &, data]]
```

[image: balls2]

Comment: Your code seems identical to the one in the OP. Can you point out the differences, and explain what the problem is and how you solved it? Could you also add your version of MMA and operating system?

Comment: Apparently, MaterialShading doesn't work properly with PlotRange.

Comment: @E.Chan-López, I provide a minimal example, however, my data is more complicated and I need to impose `PlotRange`. By the way, is it possible to use `DiscretizeRegion` instead of `PlotRange`?